# Socket.io connection errors

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I've got node v0.8.19 installed on an Ubuntu 12.04 LTS server.  I installed the npm modules for express and socket.io.

After copying the code from the first example on [How To Use](http://socket.io/#how-to-use), I'm getting an error in Chrome that looks like this:
[image]

The client is able to load up the socket.io.js source, but I'm not receiving any emit() messages on the server or client side.  Any ideas how to get this working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like your server is 54.235.156.108, but socket.io uses localhost.

Did you forget to change this from the example by any chance?